# Date format conversion PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, type-conversion, sysdate

I am supposed to calculate the age along with one decimal. I've written the following:

```
cursor customer is select fname, ename, ROUND((MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, dob)/12),1) age from table;
```

However the "dob" in the table is not in the same format (instead it is YY-MM-DD) whereas sysdate (I guess) uses something else, I get the error message ""literal does not match format string"" and would like help coming up with ideas on how to conver the string, should I convert dob or sysdate?

Comment: PL/SQL is not the language used in MySQL. Knowing which DBMS your are using will certainly help you find the right documentation.

Comment: PL/SQL is not a mysql(DBMS) language. Oracle(RDBMS) uses PL/SQL

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the column dob is string (varchar2 or char). You should convert it to date

```
to_date(dob, 'YY-MM-DD')
```

The full query will look like this

```
cursor customer is select fname, ename, ROUND((MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, to_date(dob, 'YY-MM-DD'))/12),1) age from table;
```

Comment: I think you mean "to_date()" instead of "to_char()"